# Is this a mistake?

Tags: subjunctives

Is the bold part a mistake?

> We encourage Mr. Rouhani’s wish that Iran **join** the community of civilized nations
>
> -- [*New Yorker (2013)*](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/borowitzreport/2013/09/republicans-warn-iranian-president-against-shaking-obamas-hand.html)

It seems to me like it it should read:

> We encourage Mr. Rouhani’s wish that Iran **should join**...

Comment: Why do you think it is a mistake?

Comment: Also: I've added the citation for you here, but in future could you please cite texts that you post ([see meta post here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please))

Comment: @Matt Perhaps the OP mean whether the correct form is *that Iran join* or *that Iran joins*. (Of course, it is up to the OP to clarify this; this was just my guess.)

Comment: Yes. Is this because "should" is hidden here? wish is a desire...so like "it is desirable that it be done this way."__

Comment: @kih1930 Matt's comments suggests that your question is not entirely clear. I think that the best thing to do would be to edit your questions and add a more detailed explanation of your question. (Basically, answering the question from the first comments would suffice.)

Comment: Please try to avoid asking open-ended questions like, "Is this a mistake?" without explaining **why** you think may be an error. Would you want someone to answer with no elaboration? (For example, "Yes, there is a mistake.") Both askers and answerers need to elaborate enough to communicate clearly.

Comment: [American usage:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+that+he+go%2Cwish+that+he+goes%2Cwish+that+he+should+go&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) "... that Iran join". [British usage:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+that+he+go%2Cwish+that+he+goes%2Cwish+that+he+should+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) "... that Iran should join". Bad grammar: "that Iran joins".

Comment: @PeterShor: It's not quite as clear cut as you might think: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+he+join%2Cthat+he+joins%2Cthat+he+should+join&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 6):

This use of the plain form *join*, without the *-s* that would normally be called for by a 3d-person-singular subject, is actually a 'fossil' of the now mostly defunct *subjunctive*.

The form which is used here is actually the *infinitive*, although this is only evident with the verb *BE* (since that is the only verb in English which has a distinct infinitive form). You might write of

> ... our wish that Iran ***be*** accepted into the community of civilized nations.

Today, as you say, it is usually replaced by a construction with a modal—*should* or *would* or *may*—but it survives in formal use and to a certain extent in colloquial use as well. It is more common in US English than British, but scholars report that after a long decline it is becoming used more in BE than it used to be.

Linguists differ over how the clause construction *that NP VERB* <sup>I<sup><sub>NF</sub></sup></sup> ought to be parsed. Snailboat describes it as a non-finite clause, and that reading is supported by its use of the non-finite infinitive; I'm more of a neo-traditionalist and describe it as an ordinary finite *that-*clause cast in the subjunctive mood, which elicits the infinitive form. The result is the same, whichever reading you prefer.